# Variable number AND keyword arguments?

Tags: clojure

Other than something like

```
(fn [& {:keys [more the-rest]}] ,,,)
```

Is there a way to use variable numbers of arguments and keyword arguments at the same time,
e.g.

```
(my-function arg1 arg2 some-other-args :opt1 opt1 :opt2 opt2)
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You can define your function to take arguments in whatever way you like, but the issue you will run into is how to tell the difference between ambiguous situations like:

```
(my-function arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4)
(my-function arg1 arg2 key1 val1)
```

In order to tell the difference, you'll need to write code to examine the parameters at runtime (for example checking whether the third parameter is a keyword or not). This will get ugly pretty fast.

Consequently, I wouldn't recommend going down this route. Alternatives to consider:

- Simplify your functions. If you have this many arguments, it could mean that you have "complected" too much into a single function.
- Pass all key/value arguments as a single map

Comment: I wanted to write a loop macro that executes a body of given size until a condition holds true, in which case it would return the result of a form passed by a keyboard arg (or nil otherwise). But yeah, I'll probably just do something different.